# How do u get a shell in 2.7 python input()

Tags: python-2.7

the 2.7 i know that somehow input() is vulnerable? how
are u able to execute it if there are only 2 lines ie

```
print("enter something")
a=input()
```

The expected output should be us able to give shell commands

Answer (score 0):

`input()` function will interprete the provided input as python code.

So you may do whatever is possible using a oneliner in python.

For example, given the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from os import system

print("enter something")
a=input()
print(a)
```

When run:

```
~$ ./test.py 
enter something
system('uname -a')
Linux host-l196 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u2 (2019-05-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
0
```